# Problems importing Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, setup.py, cextension

I installed pandas via anaconda and it seemed to work. However, when I want to import pandas I get the following error:

```
C extension: hashtable not built.
If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 
'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

I already tried to run this but the response is always:

```
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Maybe I am in the wrong directory but then I don't know in which I should run. I looked in `site-packages` but can't find pandas or something similar.

Then I reinstalled pandas via pip

```
git 'pip install git+git://github.com/pydata/pandas.git'
```

and during this it says:

```
Running setup.py install for pandas ... done
Successfully installed pandas-0.18.0+207.gc6110e2
```

But again I have the same error when I import pandas.

Can anyone help? What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Leni

Comment: I don't think that installing via pip will install to anaconda.  How did you install it with anaconda?

Comment: Anaconda distribution, if I remember, already has pandas. Do you read this instruction? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen
 I installed it via 'conda install pandas' since it didn't work I tried it with pip afterwards

Comment: @gunzapper, yes I followed this, if I try it again it says:

'Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .........

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /Users/lena/anaconda/envs/env:
#
pandas                    0.18.0              np111py27_0'

The same counts for anaconda I have version 4.0.0. However I still have the same error when I try to import pandas

Comment: I tried it again with conda and now it works...even though I don't know what I did different. Thanks for your effort